# How to by pass routher-outlet when showing a component in angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular5

I am new commer in angular 2 . This might be very basic question but I have dashboard page and login page. Dashboard page have a header page and menu and login page is full landing page with login form. **My problem is:**
When showing login page it shows dashboard header menu because I have set app-header before router outlet and login-app also. It is possible to by pass dashboard  element before showing login page?
**app.component.html**

```
<header-app></header-app>
<div class="container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

and login.component.html is just login form
and **header.component.html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="index.html"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/logo.png"></a>
        </div>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/Home">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/Login">Login</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/Employee">Employee</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="text-right col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <button class="sign_btn">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

but It is showing like this
http://prntscr.com/ks8xjf
Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove <header-app></header-app> from app.component.html and place it in dashboard.component.html. app.component.html should have only <router-outlet></router-outlet>

Comment: Nice man!! I am fool.. It is so simple.. Thanks.

Comment: added comment as an answer. you can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove app header component from app.component.html and place it in dashboard.component.html. app.component.html should have only rouert outlet

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**dashboard.component.html**

```
<header-app></header-app>
<other-things></other-things>
...
...
<footer></footer>
```